# Play - Cannot connect to sql server with com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, playframework, sbt

I'm working on a Play 2.8.13 project with Scala 2.12, and I want to connect to my mssql database, here's what my application.conf contains:

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=PRE_PROD;"
db.default.user="sa" db.default.password="test12"
```

There are no compile time errors from sbt, however I get the following exception:

```
Cannot initialize to database [default] 
line mark db.default.url
```

Here's what my build.sbt looks like:

```
libraryDependencies +=  guice libraryDependencies +=  ehcache
libraryDependencies +=  javaJdbc

libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" %
"3.3.3" libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-cache" %
"2.8.15" libraryDependencies +=  "com.lightbend.akka" %%
"akka-stream-alpakka-slick" % "3.0.4" libraryDependencies += 
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.19"

libraryDependencies +=  "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" %
"11.1.1.jre18-preview"
```

I already have searched over the internet, and my connection seems to be okay.
Anyone has any idea about what the problem could be?

Comment: you should specify `username`, not `user` https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#MySQL-database-engine-connection-properties
Do you test this settings via different environment? Also it is very strange to have jre18 in a lib version. Try to use jre8 or whatever java play support

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mikhail! I change to username and you right with jre . I get another error now ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72290735/for-sqlserver-please-explicitly-choose-either-sqlserver16-or-sqlserver17-as-the